# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in my pointer code c++

Tags: c++

I am currently making a program that aims to update student data using pointers and structures, but I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. This is the code that I use:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Person
{
    char name[64];
    int age;
    char gender[12];
};


int main()
{

    int loop;
    cout << "how many student to input: ";
    cin >> loop;
    struct Person *ptr[loop], d[loop];

    for(int c = 1; c < loop; c++){
        Person *ptr[c], d[c];
        ptr[c] = &d[c];
      }

    for (int a = 1; a <= loop; a++){
    cout << "Name: ";
    cin >> (*ptr[a]).name;
    cout << "Age: " ;
    cin >> (*ptr[a]).age;
    cout << "Gender: ";
    cin >> (*ptr[a]).gender;
    }

    cout << "\nDisplaying Information." << endl;
    for (int a = 1; a <= loop; a++){
    cout << "Name: " << (*ptr[a]).name << endl;
    cout <<"Age: " << (*ptr[a]).age << endl;
    cout << "Gender: " << (*ptr[a]).gender<<endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ptr` and `d` inside the first `for` loop are not the same variables as `ptr` and `d` declared right above that loop. Furthermore, after `Person *ptr[c]` declaration, valid indexes into `ptr` array are 0 through `c-1`, and `ptr[c]` exhibits undefined behavior. Drop the extra declaration inside the block.

Comment: For similar reasons, `ptr[a]` exhibits undefined behavior when `a == loop`. Arrays in C++ are zero-based, not one-based.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the way of initializing a pointer as

`Person *p = new Person()`

as opposed to

`*p = &d // assigning the address`

Also whey you say `Person *ptr[c], d[c];` inside the first for loop, you are re-initializing the arrays with different sizes each time. You don't have to do that as you have declared them before and finally array index in C++ starts from 0 to n-1, where n is the length of the array.

On making those changes your main shall look like,

```cpp
int main()
{

    int loop;
    cout << "how many student to input: ";
    cin >> loop;
    struct Person *ptr[loop], d[loop];

    for (int c = 0; c < loop; c++) {
        ptr[c] = &d[c];
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < loop; a++) {
        cout << "Name: ";
        cin >> (*ptr[a]).name;
        cout << "Age: ";
        cin >> (*ptr[a]).age;
        cout << "Gender: ";
        cin >> (*ptr[a]).gender;
    }

    cout << "\nDisplaying Information." << endl;
    for (int a = 0; a < loop; a++) {
        cout << "Name: " << (*ptr[a]).name << endl;
        cout << "Age: " << (*ptr[a]).age << endl;
        cout << "Gender: " << (*ptr[a]).gender << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing `Person *ptr[c], d[c];` inside the first `for` loop? The scope of variables declared inside a loop are limited to that loop only. Moreover, these variables will hide other variables with the same name which are declared outside the loop.

So, in your case, the statement `ptr[c] = &d[c];` inside the loop assigns to the `ptr` which is *local* to he loop and is not accessible from anywhere outside the loop.

Later on when you try to write data using `cin >> (*ptr[a]).name;`, you are cause [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as the `ptr` variable has never been initialized.

Just comment out `Person *ptr[c], d[c];` inside the `for` loop and things should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the following line from your for loop and the code should work fine:

```
Person *ptr[c], d[c];
```

Declaring these variables inside the for loop is creating new variables which have their scope limited to the for loop only. Hence, when you execute the following statement:

```
ptr[c] = &d[c];
```

inside the for loop, it's actually initializing the pointer 'ptr' declared inside the loop and not the one declared outside the loop. So, ultimately the pointer 'ptr' declared outside the for loop is never initialized, leading to the code crash.